# SlimDX Access Buffer data

Tags: c#, directx-11, slimdx

I have a Buffer with some of my vertex data. I need to be able to access the data in this Buffer to extract a single vertex from it. I'm trying to do that like this:

```
Surface surface = mBuffer.AsSurface();
DataRectangle data = surface.Map(MapFlags.Read);
```

But this returns an exception saying

> An invalid parameter was passed to the returning function.

I've also tried this using `MapFlags.Write` and `MapFlags.Discard`. No difference.

This is for DirectX11.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you buffer is either created with Dynamic/Default or Immutable flag.
Those buffers can't be read from the CPU directly.

To be able to achieve this you need to create a staging buffer, which has the same size as you other buffer.

```
BufferDescription bd = new BufferDescription()
{
    BindFlags = BindFlags.None,
    CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.Read | CpuAccessFlags.Write,
    OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
    SizeInBytes = size, //Size must be same as your other buffer
    Usage = ResourceUsage.Staging,
 };
```

Then you need to copy your vertex buffer to the staging buffer using deviceContext

```
 deviceContext.CopyResource(yourVertexBuffer, yourStagingBuffer);
```

Now you can map your staging buffer and read the data using:

```
DataStream ds = deviceContext.MapSubresource(yourStagingBuffer, MapMode.Read, MapFlags.None).Data;

//Do something with your datastream

//don't forget to unmap
deviceContext.UnmapSubresource(yourStagingBuffer, 0);
```

Comment: Your comments are always helpful. I'm facing a similar problem. I'm trying to copy (a part) of the screen as texture. I hope i can skip copying it first to a bitmap. Got some ideas?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen You have Output duplication API https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404600(v=vs.85).aspx not sure this is implemented in SlimDX (in SharpDX it does), but it is also buggy on laptops). Comment are a bit too short for detailed answer, feel free to ask as question.